# echo not displaying any value after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

Please Help me with this i want to display the value in php echo using ajax call,
the code is running without error.
the value get displayed on console `console.log(id)` when i select options from select field ,
and the value which i want to display using echo displays on console when i used `console.log(data)`.

```
<script>
$('#select-user-id').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      id: id
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(id);
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
})
</script>
```

But not displays on browser screen when i echo the value using.

```
$select_id = $_POST['id'];
echo "PHP: $select_id";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is assign the value in a span or other html tags on success.

```
success: function(data) {
     yourSpan.value = data;
}
```

Comment: Sorry didn't get you..

Comment: i want to run a mysql query based on the value i get from this call, i tried running the query using this call i get the value on console when i use ```console.log(data)``` but the value dosen't get printed on the browser screen.

Comment: @PrathameshKurade as Ainz mentioned, you need to attach that value to a tag of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Just like what Ainz had mentioned, what you would want to do is send the value to a tag and display it there.

```
<!-- Be sure that your jQuery file is added -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<select name="select-user-id" id="select-user-id">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

//Add a div as a holder for the returned values from your AJAX file
<div class="displayData"></div>

<script>
$('#select-user-id').on('change', function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  /* Also make sure that you have the correct path for your file  */
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      "id": id
    },

    success: function(data) {
      $('.displayData').html(data);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

You can also append your variable to the string like below.

```
<?php
   $select_id = $_POST['id'];
   echo 'PHP: '.$select_id;
?>
```

Comment: I get what you said sir, but the thing is the value is not displaying on brower screen. Its get displayed on the network tab in DOM.

Comment: @PrathameshKurade do you have your scripts( Jquery) added to the page?